# Flutter performance: Padding on every widget vs padding on top level listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Scenario 1:** A ListView has 10 children widgets each with a symmetric horizontal padding of 20.0.

```
return ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      child: Widget1),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      child: Widget2),
    // ...8 more like that...
  ],);
```

**Scenario 2:** A ListView has 10 children widgets without any padding. Rather a symmetric horizontal padding of 20.0 is applied to ListView itself.

```
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Widget1,
      Widget2,
    // ...8 more like that...
  ],),);
```

Will there be more overhead (in UI thread) in Scenario 1? Or will it stay almost the same.

PS: Consider that each widget is different and ListView.builder is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my view you should use the padding property of list view:-

```
return ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
  children: <Widget>[
      Widget1,
      Widget2,
    // ...8 more like that...
  ],
);
```

In first scenario, suppose you have 10 children then 10*2=20 widgets will be rendered as padding is present on them so multiply by 2. Whereas in second case only 11 will be rendered. But the example i have shared will render only 10 widgets.

Ps:-Have ignored the count of listview widget(If wanna consider then simply add 1 count to all situations).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but sometimes while tracing errors I've noticed that in case of ```Container``` widget, properties like ```Alignment``` and ```Padding``` converts to ```widgets``` and add up to the widget tree. Is it also the case with ```ListView```?

Comment: If you check the native code of ListView you can see it extends BoxScrollView-->ScrollView-->StatelessWidget. So, I Would like to add one thing that whenever you declare a widget as stateless then even if the child of the widget consists of n number of widgets, it will be consider as single widget. So, we can say that padding won't be considered as a new widget.

Answer (score 1):

All answers are good here but lake one thing to tell.

// better one first

Scenario 2: Obviously lesser work done means more performant the code is. Here we have a direct rendering of `2 + 10 = 12` widgets so whenever the widgets are rendered 12 components are rendered by the flutter's Skia engine.
Now if you deep dive into state management or updating of widgets it means the tree building again from the root meaning on every successive run of build method you render only 12 components.

Whereas

Scenario 1: The problem here with performance is that it is rendering `1 + ( 2 * 10 ) = 21` widgets in a single run of the build method. So now if we see from the point where we need to rebuild the tree it has to do more work in removing 9 more widgets than Scenario 2 and again building 9 more widgets.

PS. You could also optimize some of the static widgets that don't require to be rebuilt again and again with the const keyword.

One more thing I would like to add this is not a heavy performance increment, what I mean to say is you may not be able to verify the boost with dev tools as well.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the difference is so trivial that it should not be the deciding factor for you. Instead, you should determine which method makes more sense to your business logic, or improves your code readability, or both.

Strictly speaking, directly adding a padding to the ListView is slightly more performant, because slightly fewer calculations is needed. Also, it's worth noting that `Padding` widget, won't actually "draw an invisible container, draw some invisible gap, and draw its child in the middle" - this is NOT how it works. In reality it's far more efficient: In short, widgets are laid out in one-pass O(n) operation, by traversing the widget tree just once. When going down, it passes parent's constraints, and when coming up, it passes children's sizes. In the case of a `Padding` widget, it simply modifies the parent's constraint when passing down, so there is really almost no overhead to worry about.

It's also worth noting that `ListView` has `padding` property, so directly using that, is a 3rd option that you have not mentioned. Be aware that ListView's padding property does not behave the same as wrapping it with `Padding` widget either, and you might want to worry about SafeArea too. You can easily figure these out with some experiments. Again, all 3 methods have trivial performance cost, you should choose the one that makes the most sense to your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

first scenario is better since your widget tree is smaller

Comment: Are you sure about it??

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.